# git clone with ssh not working but connects manually - wsl ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ssh, 22.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, git

I'm trying to clone repo from the gitlab. I've already added the ssh keys in my account. What's supposed to happen when I clone via ssh is that the browser will open for authentication via duoconnect. I've already installed duoconnect on my wsl & windows too. I've installed wslu and xdg-utils package. But the browser doesn't open for authentication. It works fine on my windows but doesn't work on my linux subsytem.

This is my **config**:

```
Host <server>
    HostName <server>
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519

Host <server>
        ProxyCommand duoconnect -host=%h:%p -relay=<server> -log ~/duoconnect.log
```

`xdg-open` manages to launch my browser, when i try to run this manually on the terminal `duoconnect -host=%h:%p -relay=<server> -log ~/duoconnect.log`, it opens the browser, logs and authenticates using duo, it's the same with `ssh -v <server>` but when I use `git clone` using ssh, it fails to open the browser, it also doesn't log anything

**error message:**

```
ssh: connect to host <server> port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```